# Variable assignment in an if-condition statement

Tags: c++

I have seen some codes that perform variable assignment in the `if` condition, for example:

```
if((data->symStem = sym.isStem())==TRUE)  //if condition
{
   // do something
}
```

To my understanding, in the if condition above, `sym.isStem()` is first assigned to `data->symStem`, and thereafter, the equality condition (for `sym.isStem()` or `data->sysStem`) is evaluated. Please correct me if there is something wrong.

I wonder if there is any particular reason to do so except that the codes are more compact.

Comment: You're right about its meaning. There's no good reason to do it in a simple `if` statement like this one. In more complex situations it can simplify logic involving an `if ... else if ...` ladder, when such an assignment is only supposed to be made under certain circumstances. I know, that's a lot of handwaving. A proper example won't be readable in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no reason to do it other than writing it in 1 line vs 2 lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

In C++17, this gets a certain twist - now you are not only allowed to assign variables, you are also allowed to create and initialize variables in the `if` condition (it is called if statement with initializer):

```
if (int a = foo(); a != 0) {
//...
}
```

That has a benefit of being able to introduce scoped variables without having to put new set of artifical braces around it, like pre-C++17 you'd have to do

```
{
int a = foo();
if (a != 0) {
//...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assignment is typically implemented as

```
struct foo {
    foo& operator=(const foo& other) {
        // do the assignment
        return *this;
    }
};
```

and the reason is to allow chaining as in your example. There is really not much more to it than saving a line of code.